# How to make node js controller not so messy?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I was making my nodeJs app and I realized that my controller is a little bit messy,so I tried to decompose the logic by creating various function but when I see the result, I have a feeling that something wrong with my code . I mean, is it ok to use async function in another async function, or to use async functions the way I use them. Could anyone make a little code-review, I would be grateful for any help.

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

import Role from "../../models/Role.js";
import User from "../../models/User.js";

export default class UserControler {
    public async createUser(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any>{
        try {
            async function getHashedPassword(password: any): Promise<string> {
                const salt: string = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                const hashedPassword: string = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
                
                return hashedPassword;
            };
            async function getDefaultRoleId(): Promise<string> {
                const [roleData, createdRole] = await Role.findOrCreate({
                    where: {
                        name: 'User',
                    },
                    defaults: {
                        name: 'User'
                    }
                });
                const roleId: string = roleData.getDataValue('_id');
                
                return roleId;
            };
            async function emailExists(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
                const user = await User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        email: email,
                    }
                });

                if (user) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            
            const _emailExists: boolean = await emailExists(req.body.email)
            if(_emailExists) return res.status(400).json({exists: true});

            await User.create({
                role: await getDefaultRoleId(),
                email: req.body.email,
                hidden: false,
                password: await getHashedPassword(req.body.password)
            }).then((data) => {
                res.json({data: data});
            })
        } catch (err: any) {
            res.status(400).json({error: err});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would encourage you to follow the practice of creation of `services`. I can see from your code that you already have the `controller` & `models` in place. The only piece you're missing are `services`. You can move all your logic to the service file and keep your controller as thin as possible.

###### Sample Implementation:

```ts
// userController.ts file
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { emailExists } from "./userService";

export default class UserController {
  public async createUser(req: Request, res: Response): Promise {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      const _emailExists: boolean = await emailExists(email);
      if (_emailExists) return res.status(400).json({ exists: true });

      const user = await createUser(email, password);
      res.json({ data: user });
    } catch (err: any) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    }
  }
}
```

Now create a `userService.ts` file, `export` the methods and then reference the required ones in your main controller file.

```ts
// userService.ts
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import Role from "../../models/Role.js";
import User from "../../models/User.js";

export const createUser = async (
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<User> => {
  return User.create({
    role: await getDefaultRoleId(),
    email,
    hidden: false,
    password: await getHashedPassword(password),
  });
};

export const getHashedPassword = async (password: any): Promise<string> => {
  const salt: string = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword: string = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  return hashedPassword;
};

export const getDefaultRoleId = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const [roleData, createdRole] = await Role.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      name: "User",
    },
    defaults: {
      name: "User",
    },
  });
  const roleId: string = roleData.getDataValue("_id");
  return roleId;
};

export const emailExists = async (email: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
  if (user) return true;
  return false;
};
```

###### References:

- [Model-Routes-Controllers-Services Code Structure](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/32332/model-routes-controllers-services-code-structure)
- [Node Service-oriented Architecture](https://www.codementor.io/@evanbechtol/node-service-oriented-architecture-12vjt9zs9i)

Comment: Happy to help. Worth mentioning, you can even create another layer called `repositories` which will be responsible for interacting with the DB. The services will never really communicate directly with the DB. This approach is useful while unit testing you application. You can find more information over the links attached in the references.